# Differences between create our own UoW/Repository vs using DbContext directly

Tags: .net, repository, entity, dbcontext

The description for `DbContext` says :"A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns...". But many developers tend to create their own repositories and UoW.

Should I use `DbContext` and `DbSet` directly or should be there my own Repositories ? What are the differences.

Is there any problem if we use the `DbContext` directly ? How about if I switch from MS SQL to Oracle in the future ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)

> Other times, you may want to write your own application-specific Unit
>   of Work interface or class that wraps the inner Unit of Work from your
>   persistence tool. You may do this for a number of reasons. You might
>   want to add application-specific logging, tracing, or error handling
>   to transaction management. Perhaps you want to encapsulate the
>   specifics of your persistence tooling from the rest of the
>   application. You might want this extra encapsulation to make it easier
>   to swap out persistence technologies later. Or you might want to
>   promote testability in your system. Many of the built-in Unit of Work
>   implementations from common persistence tools are difficult to deal
>   with in automated unit testing scenarios.

Come back to your questions.

> Should I use DbContext and DbSet directly or should be there my own
>   Repositories ?

In fact, there is no problem when you put `DbContext` and `DbSet` into your repositories. We will ask by ourselves we would like to test more easier ot not. If we want design a framework testing everything we should not use `DbContext` and `DbSet` directly as well into your `Repositories`. We should use interface `IDbContextFactory` which is use to provide `DbContext`, just my two cents.

To help you have many views about repository you can take reference the link below to consider options between repository and `DbContext`.

http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/

> Is there any problem if we use the `DbContext` directly ?

No, there is no problem if you use `DbContext` directly. But it will messy many business rules and a tons of scale up issues as centralize database, difficult to test and violate separate of concern in design principle.

> How about if I switch from MS SQL to Oracle in the future ?

Actually, there is no problem when you switch between MS SQL and Oracle in the future. You just only change data provider follow the link below when use `DbContext` of Entity Framework.

http://www.devart.com/news/2008/directs475.html

or 
[MS Entity Framework Oracle Provider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1395)